# Memory Monitor using ':C XXXX' in RDi not Showing Variable Value

Tags: rpgle, rational-developer-for-i

When monitoring memory using the `:C XXXX` option, the memory values do not show when debugging. You can monitor up to 4000 characters by using the `:C` option when monitoring memory:

[image]

I have ran into this problem twice now. I am using `IBM Rational Developer for i Version: 9.6.0.0`, with the `Java JDK/JRE v8u45`.

Here are the values when debugging, and my data structure definition:

[image]

```
dcl-ds dsSQL qualified inz;
  fullStmt varchar( 9360 ) inz;
end-ds;
```

Once I click on the element, all I see is ``. There is nothing in the value but that, but you can clearly see that `dsSQL.fullStmt` is not empty. I use this option daily and 99.99% of the time it works fine. I have to restart a million times, reset RDi to start with `-c` and recompile the program over and over to get it to work right.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I would give you the 'Error Log' but it is constantly filled and nothing in there seems to point to that issue. When adding or looking at that variable during debug, no errors are thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to update to the latest 9.6.0.6 release.  They have fixed at least a few memory problems with the debugger between your release and the latest.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038481

Comment: My hope was not to have to do that lol. Just updated. Let's see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Was forced to update to see if it fixed it, and for now it did. Luckily it seems stable now.